# Angular custom FormControl & AsyncValidator Submit not working on first click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have somes Forms, that usese some custom FormControls, but when I place one of these FormControls last, it causes the Submit button to not work on first click (without prior leaving the last input field with a click)

**Custom FormControl**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myinput',
  templateUrl: './myinput.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myinput.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MatFormFieldControl,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyinputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyinputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class MyinputComponent
  implements
    ControlValueAccessor,
    MatFormFieldControl<string>,
    AsyncValidator,
    OnInit,
    OnDestroy
{
  public static nextId = 0;

  private _disabled = false;
  private _required = false;
  private _placeholder: string;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  public form: FormGroup<stuffForm> = this.formbuilder.group({
    importantStuff: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [asyncValidator()],
    }),
  });

  public stateChanges: Subject<void> = new Subject();
  public focused: boolean = false;
  public touched: boolean = false;
  public controlType?: string | undefined = 'app-myinput';
  public id: string = `app-myinput${MyinputComponent.nextId++}`;
  public onChange: any = () => {};
  public onTouched: any = () => {};
  public onValidatorChanged: any = () => {};
  public shouldLabelFloat: boolean;
  public ngControl: NgControl;
  constructor(
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
    private _injector: Injector,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_FORM_FIELD) public _formField: MatFormField
  ) {}

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl<any, any>
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.form.controls.importantStuff.statusChanges.pipe(
      filter((status: FormControlStatus) => status != 'PENDING'),
      map((status: FormControlStatus) => {
        return this.form.controls.importantStuff.errors;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidatorChanged = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this._injector.get(NgControl) != null) {
      this.ngControl = this._injector.get(NgControl);
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
    this.subscription = this.form.controls.importantStuff.valueChanges
      .pipe(filter((x) => x != ''))
      .subscribe(() => this.form.markAllAsTouched());
  }

  autofilled?: boolean | undefined;
  public get empty() {
    return !this.form.value;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/no-input-rename
  @Input('aria-describedby') userAriaDescribedBy: string;

  @Input()
  get placeholder(): string {
    return this._placeholder;
  }
  set placeholder(value: string) {
    this._placeholder = value;
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get required(): boolean {
    return this._required;
  }
  set required(value: BooleanInput) {
    this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get disabled(): boolean {
    return this._disabled;
  }
  set disabled(value: BooleanInput) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    this._disabled ? this.form.disable() : this.form.enable();
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get value(): string | null {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      return this.form.controls.importantStuff.value;
    }
    return null;
  }
  set value(importantStuff: string | null) {
    this.form.controls.importantStuff.setValue(importantStuff);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  get errorState(): boolean {
    return this.form.invalid && this.touched;
  }

  onFocusIn(event: FocusEvent) {
    if (!this.focused) {
      this.focused = true;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    }
  }

  onFocusOut(event: FocusEvent) {
    if (
      !this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.relatedTarget as Element)
    ) {
      this.touched = true;
      this.focused = false;
      this.onTouched();
      this.stateChanges.next();
    }
  }

  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]) {
    const controlElement = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '.example-tel-input-container'
    )!;
    controlElement.setAttribute('aria-describedby', ids.join(' '));
  }

  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.onTouched();
  }

  writeValue(importantStuff: string): void {
    this.form.controls.importantStuff.setValue(importantStuff);
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  public change(value: Event) {
    this.form.controls.importantStuff.setValue(
      (value.target as HTMLInputElement).value
    );
    this.onChange(this.form.controls.importantStuff.value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}

export interface stuffForm {
  importantStuff: FormControl<string | null>;
}
```

**Custom FormControl HTML**

```html
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-label>importantStuff</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    formControlName="importantStuff"
    (change)="change($event)"
    (focusin)="onFocusIn($event)"
    (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)"
    (input)="onChange(form.controls.importantStuff.value)"
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

**From TS**

```
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public form = this.formbuilder.group<StoreForm>({
    some: new FormControl('', {
      nonNullable: true,
    }),
    importantStuff: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
  });

  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  public submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

  public isValid(): boolean {
    return this.form.valid; // This is a method, because in the original code, there are more requirements
  }
}

export interface StoreForm {
  some: FormControl<string>;
  importantStuff: FormControl<string>;
}
```

**Form HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Some Field</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="some" type="text" matInput />
  </mat-form-field>
  <app-myinput formControlName="importantStuff"></app-myinput>
  <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!isValid()" type="submit">Ok</button>
</form>
```

I enter a value into the custom formControl and the async validator inside the custom control evaluates that the field is valid, the Submit button will be enabled. I click on the submit button an nothing happens;

The form re-validates the itself on focusout, which disables the button before the `submit` function is called. After realizing that the value is indeed valid (as it was before) the button will be re-enabled and will call `submit` on next click.

[Stackblitz Reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-69jvju?file=src%2Fmy-form%2Fmy-form.component.html,src%2Fapp.module.ts)

Unfortunetly, Angular Material Design does not work in the Repro, but since it reproduces the behavior, I think it is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the

```html
    (change)="change($event)"
```

from the Custom Control.
The change Event was called on focusout, causing validation to run again (faster  than the button could update its disabled state) resulting in the problem behavior